# Can we create custom web services with support of WPML

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am creating custom web services using plugin json-api. I have created a custom plugin with support of json-api to get all data. I am creating these services for my Android and IOS app. Website is running in two language and also woocommerce shopping cart.

My question is: Can we get both language data with custom query?

Please help me to solve this issue.